How to obfuscate Java code similarly to this example?
I am looking for ways to obfuscate my Java code to achieve a level of complexity similar to the following example:
public class GuiPlayerInfo extends GuiPlayerStats {
  public void func_73863_a(int llllIllllIIlIII, int llllIllllIIIlll, float llllIllllIIlIll) {
    llllIllllIIlIIl.func_146276_q_();
    llllIllllIIlIIl.field_146297_k.func_110434_K().func_110577_a(guiTexture);
    GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73729_b(llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft, llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop, lIIlIlI[3], lIIlIlI[3], llllIllllIIlIIl.xSize, llllIllllIIlIIl.ySize);
    int var10001 = llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[4];
    int var10002 = llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[5];
    int var10003 = llllIllllIIlIIl.xSize;
    int var10004;
    if (llIlIIl(llllIllllIIlIIl.isPlayerOnline())) {
      var10004 = lIIlIlI[3];
      "".length();
      if ("  ".length() == "   ".length()) {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      var10004 = lIIlIlI[6];
    }

    llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73729_b(var10001, var10002, var10003, var10004, lIIlIlI[7], lIIlIlI[6]);
    if (llIlIlI(llllIllllIIlIIl.playTimeInfo)) {
      llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73732_a(llllIllllIIlIIl.field_146289_q, llllIllllIIlIIl.playerName, llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[8], llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[9], lIIlIlI[10]);
      String llllIllllIIIlIl = TimeInterval.values();
      Exception llllIllllIIIlII = lIIlIlI[3];

      while(llIlIll(llllIllllIIIlII, llllIllllIIIlIl.length)) {
        llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73731_b(llllIllllIIlIIl.field_146289_q, llllIllllIIIlIl[llllIllllIIIlII].translate(llllII[lIIlIlI[3]]), llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[11], llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[12] + llllIllllIIIlII * lIIlIlI[13], lIIlIlI[10]);
        FontRenderer var7 = llllIllllIIlIIl.field_146289_q;
        String var8 = llllII[lIIlIlI[14]];
        Object[] var9 = new Object[lIIlIlI[14]];
        var9[lIIlIlI[3]] = Double.toString(llllIllllIIlIIl.playTimeInfo.getIntervalTimeHours(llllIllllIIIlIl[llllIllllIIIlII]));
        llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73731_b(var7, StatCollector.func_74837_a(var8, var9), llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[15], llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[12] + llllIllllIIIlII * lIIlIlI[13], lIIlIlI[10]);
        ++llllIllllIIIlII;
        "".length();
        if (((246 ^ 198) & ~(112 ^ 64)) > 0) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    llllIllllIIlIIl.func_73732_a(llllIllllIIlIIl.field_146289_q, llllIllllIIlIIl.playerName, llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[8], llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[9], lIIlIlI[10]);
    int[] llllIllllIIlIlI = RenderUtils.bindTextureAndGetSize(llllIllllIIlIIl.playerName);
    RenderUtils.drawPlayerHead(llllIllllIIlIIl.guiLeft + lIIlIlI[13], llllIllllIIlIIl.guiTop + lIIlIlI[16], lIIlIlI[17], lIIlIlI[17], llllIllllIIlIlI);
    super.func_73863_a(llllIllllIIlIII, llllIllllIIIlll, llllIllllIIlIll);
  }

  private static boolean llIlIIl(int var0) {
    return var0 != 0;
  }

  private static String lIlIIII(String llllIlllIIlllII, String llllIlllIIllIll) {
    llllIlllIIlllII = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(llllIlllIIlllII.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    boolean llllIlllIIllIlI = new StringBuilder();
    double llllIlllIIllIIl = llllIlllIIllIll.toCharArray();
    Exception llllIlllIIllIII = lIIlIlI[3];
    short llllIlllIIlIlll = llllIlllIIlllII.toCharArray();
    int llllIlllIIlIllI = llllIlllIIlIlll.length;
    Exception llllIlllIIlIlIl = lIIlIlI[3];

    do {
      if (!llIlIll(llllIlllIIlIlIl, llllIlllIIlIllI)) {
        return String.valueOf(llllIlllIIllIlI);
      }

      char llllIlllIlIIIlI = llllIlllIIlIlll[llllIlllIIlIlIl];
      llllIlllIIllIlI.append((char)(llllIlllIlIIIlI ^ llllIlllIIllIIl[llllIlllIIllIII % llllIlllIIllIIl.length]));
      "".length();
      ++llllIlllIIllIII;
      ++llllIlllIIlIlIl;
      "".length();
    } while(-" ".length() <= (5 ^ 30 ^ 130 ^ 157));

    return null;
  }

  private static void llIIlIl() {
    lIIlIlI = new int[19];
    lIIlIlI[0] = (108 ^ 14) + 74 + 4 - -23 + 44 - (36 ^ 118) + (187 ^ 180);
    lIIlIlI[1] = (215 ^ 167) + (63 ^ 24) - (10 ^ 64) + (8 ^ 51);
    lIIlIlI[2] = "  ".length();
    lIIlIlI[3] = (149 + 116 - 244 + 168 ^ 81 + 80 - 156 + 168) & (67 ^ 58 ^ 92 ^ 53 ^ -" ".length());
    lIIlIlI[4] = 119 ^ 106;
    lIIlIlI[5] = 22 ^ 0;
    lIIlIlI[6] = 9 ^ 80 ^ 53 ^ 107;
    lIIlIlI[7] = 95 ^ 89;
    lIIlIlI[8] = 116 ^ 99 ^ 14 ^ 125;
    lIIlIlI[9] = 111 ^ 97;
    lIIlIlI[10] = -" ".length() & -1 & 16777215;
    lIIlIlI[11] = 180 ^ 129 ^ 97 ^ 92;
    lIIlIlI[12] = 239 ^ 155 ^ 91 ^ 29;
    lIIlIlI[13] = 240 ^ 172 ^ 16 ^ 70;
    lIIlIlI[14] = " ".length();
    lIIlIlI[15] = 143 + 126 - 107 + 23 ^ 151 + 132 - 128 + 38;
    lIIlIlI[16] = 15 + 146 - 19 + 13 ^ 95 + 7 - 89 + 131;
    lIIlIlI[17] = 79 ^ 95;
    lIIlIlI[18] = "   ".length();
  }

  private static void lIlIIll() {
    llllII = new String[lIIlIlI[18]];
    llllII[lIIlIlI[3]] = lIIllIl("2lK4k12OKdv6daXXE956fCcAd+7ZW5ZDyUz57TAj5h8=", "ZAyxk");
    llllII[lIIlIlI[14]] = lIlIIII("KSw3DhIgJnoBBiVsJAoSNScmMhw8bDwJBj4x", "LBTfs");
    llllII[lIIlIlI[2]] = lIIllIl("elgqZLI+MQseFvmEczgmVkJiSwSK6bul1jjoIl5yWYym7w/ijOPDJA==", "Dofln");
  }

  public void func_73866_w_() {
    llllIllllIlIlll.xSize = lIIlIlI[0];
    llllIllllIlIlll.ySize = lIIlIlI[1];
    llllIllllIlIlll.guiLeft = (llllIllllIlIlll.field_146294_l - llllIllllIlIlll.xSize) / lIIlIlI[2];
    llllIllllIlIlll.guiTop = (llllIllllIlIlll.field_146295_m - llllIllllIlIlll.ySize) / lIIlIlI[2];
    super.func_73866_w_();
    llllIllllIlIlll.loadingAnim = new LoadingAnim(llllIllllIlIlll.guiLeft + llllIllllIlIlll.xSize / lIIlIlI[2], llllIllllIlIlll.guiTop + llllIllllIlIlll.ySize / lIIlIlI[2]);
    llllIllllIlIlll.requestPlayerInfo();
  }

  protected int getTabIndex() {
    return lIIlIlI[2];
  }

  private boolean isPlayerOnline() {
    int llllIlllIlIlllI = llllIlllIllIIII.field_146297_k.field_71439_g.field_71174_a.field_147303_b.iterator();

    do {
      if (!llIlIIl(llllIlllIlIlllI.hasNext())) {
        return (boolean)lIIlIlI[3];
      }

      Object llllIlllIllIIIl = llllIlllIlIlllI.next();
      short llllIlllIlIllII = (net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiPlayerInfo)llllIlllIllIIIl;
      if (llIlIIl(llllIlllIlIllII.field_78831_a.equalsIgnoreCase(llllIlllIllIIII.playerName))) {
        return (boolean)lIIlIlI[14];
      }

      "".length();
    } while(((167 ^ 175) & ~(90 ^ 82)) <= 0);

    return (boolean)("  ".length() & ~"  ".length());
  }

  protected boolean shouldDrawLoadingAnim() {
    int var10000;
    if (llIllII(llllIllllIIIIIl.playTimeInfo)) {
      var10000 = lIIlIlI[14];
      "".length();
      if ("  ".length() >= "   ".length()) {
        return (boolean)((107 ^ 88) & ~(33 ^ 18));
      }
    } else {
      var10000 = lIIlIlI[3];
    }

    return (boolean)var10000;
  }

  private void requestPlayerInfo() {
    llllIlllIlllllI.playTimeInfo = null;
    PacketHandler.networkWrapper.sendToServer(new PacketPlayerInfoRequest(llllIlllIlllllI.playerName));
  }

  static {
    llIIlIl();
    lIlIIll();
    guiTexture = new ResourceLocation(llllII[lIIlIlI[2]]);
  }

  private static boolean llIlIll(int var0, int var1) {
    return var0 < var1;
  }

  private static String lIIllIl(String llllIlllIIIlIlI, String llllIlllIIIlIll) {
    try {
      float llllIlllIIIlIII = new SecretKeySpec(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(llllIlllIIIlIll.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), "Blowfish");
      char llllIlllIIIIlll = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
      llllIlllIIIIlll.init(lIIlIlI[2], llllIlllIIIlIII);
      return new String(llllIlllIIIIlll.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(llllIlllIIIlIlI.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (Exception var4) {
      float llllIlllIIIlIII = var4;
      llllIlllIIIlIII.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  public void setPlayTimeInfo(PlayTimeInfo llllIlllIlllIIl) {
    llllIlllIlllIlI.playTimeInfo = llllIlllIlllIIl;
  }

  private static boolean llIllII(Object var0) {
    return var0 == null;
  }

  private static boolean llIlIlI(Object var0) {
    return var0 != null;
  }

  public GuiPlayerInfo(String llllIllllIlllII) {
    llllIllllIllIll.playerName = llllIllllIlllII;
  }
}

My goal is to implement encryption for method names and calls. I want to ensure that the obfuscation is effective in making the code harder to understand and analyze.
Please note that this is a regular Java application (not Android or any other framework).
What tools or techniques can I use to achieve this level of obfuscation in my Java project? Any specific configuration examples or libraries would be greatly appreciated!

Intuitively, this seems similar to obfuscation performed by ProGuard, which provides detailed documentation and configuration instructions for its operations.
It's important to note that if your project has some hard-coded reflection operations, such as A.class.getMethod("method1"), you might not be able to retrieve the method method1 from A.class after obfuscation because its method name has been changed.
Fortunately, you can see some clues in the ProGuard logs during the obfuscation process.
However, there may still be subtle differences that could cause your project to malfunction after obfuscation. In such cases, you'll have to adjust the ProGuard obfuscation configuration incrementally based on the hints provided to restore normal functionality.
